# Java If (conditions) are NOT TRUE syntax for throwing Exception

Tags: java, exception, syntax

I'm trying to use exception blocks for this project, which needs to throw an exception if the substring does not match "title" or "author". I want to use an if (condition) is false statement to throw my exception, but I know that for strings I can't compare with != because operators compare addresses and not content.

What would be the correct syntax to say if (condition1 || condition2 ) **is false** {
throw exception}

> ```
>     public String getLongest(String property) throws IllegalNovelPropertyException{
>        String longest = "";
>       if (property.equalsIgnoreCase("author" ) || property.equalsIgnoreCase("title" ) is false);
>        {
>            throw new IllegalNovelPropertyException("Bad property. Substring must be title or author."); }
> ```

Comment: `if (!(condition1 || condition2 ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to write `is false` in Java is through using negation `!`. Your code would become:

```java
if(!(property.equalsIgnoreCase("author") || property.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))) {
    // Code.
}
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite that logic to the following equivalent (based on preference):

```java
if(!property.equalsIgnoreCase("author") && !property.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
    // Code.
}
```

Edit: Note that you are using a semicolon (`;`) in `if(); {}`, whereas that syntax in Java is `if() {}` without the semicolon.